# C# Add rows to Microsoft Access table

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, records

I want to import an Excel file to a Access table.

I have a code that works well the first time. It is making a loop through all the sheets of the excel file, and it inserts the records.

At the second time, I get an exception:

> "The table already exists"

I know that the table already exists in the Access file! I want to insert more records on it! I don't want to drop it!

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Here it is the code:

```
      class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string ExcelFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FilesLocation"];
        string AccessFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AccessFileLocation"];

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ExcelFiles, "*.xlsx");

        foreach (string excelFile in files)
        {

                string[] sheets = ListSheetInExcel(excelFile).ToArray();

                foreach (string sheetName in sheets)
                {

                    ImportSpreadsheet(
                        excelFile,
                        sheetName.Replace("'", ""),
                        "MyTable",
                       AccessFile);

                }

        }

    }


    public static void ImportSpreadsheet(string ExcelfileName, string ExcelsheetName, string AccesstableName, string AccessDatabase)
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sbConnection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        String strExtendedProperties = String.Empty;
        sbConnection.DataSource = ExcelfileName;
        if (Path.GetExtension(ExcelfileName).Equals(".xls"))//for 97-03 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
        }
        else if (Path.GetExtension(ExcelfileName).Equals(".xlsx"))  //for 2007 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
        }
        sbConnection.Add("Extended Properties", strExtendedProperties);


        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sbConnection.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database="
                        + AccessDatabase + "].["
                        + AccesstableName + "] FROM ["
                        + ExcelsheetName + "]";

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE !!!!!!!!
                }
            }
            catch (DbException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}\r\n   Stack Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    public static List<string> ListSheetInExcel(string filePath)
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sbConnection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        String strExtendedProperties = String.Empty;
        sbConnection.DataSource = filePath;
        if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xls"))//for 97-03 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";//HDR=ColumnHeader,IMEX=InterMixed
        }
        else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).Equals(".xlsx"))  //for 2007 Excel file
        {
            sbConnection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            strExtendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
        }
        sbConnection.Add("Extended Properties", strExtendedProperties);

        List<string> listSheet = new List<string>();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(sbConnection.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))//checks whether row contains '_xlnm#_FilterDatabase' or sheet name(i.e. sheet name always ends with $ sign)
                {
                    listSheet.Add(drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return listSheet;
    }
}
```

Comment: You most likely are trying to create the table each time instead of checking that it exists. Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: I'm going to channel my inner Raymond Chen and use my psychic powers to say that you have the CREATE TABLE call inside your loop. As crashmstr said, posting code would help.

Comment: I noticed you posted `some of the code`, but you need to post all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

The command "INSERT INTO" needs to create a new table.

The solution is to build a command without that need:

```
 cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [MS Access;Database="
                        + AccessDatabase + "].["
                        + AccesstableName + "] SELECT * FROM ["
                        + ExcelsheetName + "]";
```